# Javascript Ignoring Tags in document.write

Tags: javascript

Consider the following code:

```
document.write("a<b");
```

When I try to run that, it makes a outputs displaying the letter `a`. I think this is because it thinks that I want to start a tag, therefor excluding the rest. Is there a way to bypass this? A way to still display the `<`, and the rest of the line, too? It seems that the escape character, `\`, does not work (or am I doing something wrong?)

Thanks

Comment: It displays everything specified inside the alert

Comment: Odd.... I'm using Brackets IDE

Comment: Where is the `document.write`?

Comment: Well, it was originally in `document.write`, I just changed it to alert for purposes of easy reading

Comment: @APCoding—that changes the context of the question. Strings passed to *document.write* are parsed as markup, so `<` will be seen as starting a tag. Not so with *window.alert*, where it's just a character in a string.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense. I'll change the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does think you are writing a tag for `document.write()`, instead use `&lt;`, as in less-than:

```
document.write("a&lt;b");
```